# How to get the Count of an IObservable

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive

I'm lost.

I try to get some aggregate values (mostly `Count`) from a long stream of database records. We used to used regular linq, but the volume of data has become to big to fit into the memory. I was thinking to *simply* convert the queries to IObservable to get a 'streaming' result. But I must be missing something. Most samples and documentation do not seem to account for this scenario. Perhaps Rx is not the correct toolset for this.

So for my repro of the problem, I just generate some random data. I then group it and expect number of items in each group.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // lots of DB records; from IEnumerable to IObservable
    var records= //GetRecords();
    ///*
        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(11))
                     .Take(100)
                     .Select(i => new { Group = DateTime.Now.Millisecond % 10 });
    //*/
    var result = from r in records
                 group r by r.Group into g
                 select new
                 {
                     Key = g.Key,
                     Count = g.Count()
                 };

    foreach (var item in result.ToEnumerable())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", item.Key, item.Count.Wait());
    }
}
```

The result will only give me a value for the first item:

```
8 - 12
4 - 0
0 - 0
5 - 0
1 - 0
7 - 0
2 - 0
3 - 0
9 - 0
6 - 0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does count.Wait() do?

Comment: Rx seems like a weird choice. Your application is not about events but about records which is a very good fit for `IEnumerable<T>` and LINQ. You do not have to load all your records to count them. Create an iterator block that simply iterates your records one at a time and then apply LINQ to the resulting `IEnumerable<T>`. You might even be able to use P-LINQ to speed up your aggregations.

Comment: We are using LINQ at the moment, but the aggregations that we do require that we load all the data in memory. Which used to work as expected. It's about memory usage, not performance.
Incidently our records represent Events, I'll modify the names to avoid the confusion with Rx and e.g. MouseEvents

Comment: If you have to load all data in memory to perform the aggregation then I cannot see how you can reduce memory usage by using Rx? Or any other solution for that matter.

Comment: The data that we load is stored as blobs in the DB (events in a CQRS/ES scenario), so the simplest solution was to load all data in memory and then use LINQ to objects to do the aggregations.
Using Rx, we can load the data and have the aggregations compute the values in a streaming way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Count()` returns an `IObservable<int>`, and you are subscribing to it late, that is, when all your values from `events` have been observed. I'm not 100% sure about the behaviour of `Group` but it seems you need to subscribe earlier to `Count()` to avoid missing elements. Add `.ToTask()` to `.Count()` and see what happens. That way, calling `Wait()` makes sense after all.

Comment: Ok, so converting it to a Task does the subscription and allows me to get the result back. Thx